# Multiple duplicate values are not displayed from list

Tags: python, duplicates

I am trying to get duplicate values from a list using the following function.
The function is only displaying the first or one duplicate value.

Example list is -

```
in_list = [sam, Michael, sam, john, john]
```

There are two duplicate values in the list **sam** and **john**.
But only **sam** is displayed.

```
def DuplicateGuideCheck(in_list, report):
    unique = set(in_list) 
    for each in in_list: 
      count = in_list.count(each)
      if count > 1:
         print each
         report.write(each)
         report.write('\n')
         return True
    print "NONE"
    report.write('NONE\n')
    return False
```

Comment: That's because you `return True` as soon as you find the first.  You cannot return until you have gone through the entire list.

Comment: A count that is greater than 1 does not necessarily indicate a duplicate - e.g., a count of 3 would indicate triplicate. That may be your intent but that makes your function name a misnomer. You create a set (*unique*) but don't use it. Also, you seem to be using a very old version of Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used `return` whenever you get the first item whose count is more than 1. Once it is caught your function return back leaving the rest of the values to be not evaluated.

one approach to solving the problem. where you count the frequency of each word, and see if any one of them is more than 1 if found then add that to duplicates set.

```
def DuplicateGuideCheck(in_list, report):
    freq = {}
    duplicates = set()
    for val in in_list:
        if val not in freq:
            freq[val] = 0
        freq[val] += 1
        if freq[val] > 1:
           duplicates.add(val)
    if duplicates:
       for val in duplicates:
           report.write(val)
           report.write("\n")
    else:
         report.write("None\n")

    return True if duplicates else False
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the proper indentation of your code.. but I properly indented your code and here is the reason why `john` is not displayed.

```
def DuplicateGuideCheck(in_list, report):
    unique = set(in_list) 
    for each in in_list: 
        count = in_list.count(each)
        if count > 1:
            print(each)
            report.write(each)
            report.write('\n')
            return True
    print("NONE")
    report.write('NONE\n')
    return False
```

This is your code... You are returning `True` when you found a `element` whose `count` is `more than 1`. So the function will return `True` after finding `sam`. The `return` keyword will brings the execution of the program outside the function after returning the given value. So after finding `sam`, no more list elements are `iterated`.

Use the following code to get all the elements that occurs more than once:

```
def DuplicateGuideCheck(in_list, report):
    unique = set() 
    for each in in_list: 
        count = in_list.count(each)
        if count > 1 and each not in unique:
            unique.add(each)
            print(each)
            report.write(str(each))
            report.write('\n')
    print("NONE")
    report.write('NONE\n')
```

The above code has a `set` data structure which will monitors the elements which are already wrote to the `report` so that we write the repeating elements only once and I don't used `return` keyword so that all the elements are iterated. Thank you!!!

`NOTE: My code is not an optimized approach. I just corrected your mistakes.`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate is defined as: having two corresponding or identical parts.

i.e., if a value occurs exactly twice in the list then it's a duplicate.

However, we can have a version of the function that handles the strict meaning (exactly twice) or the less strict meaning of "more than one".

```
import sys
from operator import eq, gt

def DuplicateGuideCheck(in_list, report, strict=True):
    b, op = (2, eq) if strict else (1, gt)
    dup = False
    for name in set(in_list):
        if op(in_list.count(name), b):
            print(name, file=report)
            dup = True
    if not dup:
        print('NONE', file=report)
    return dup

lst = ['sam', 'Michael', 'sam', 'john', 'john', 'sam'] 

DuplicateGuideCheck(lst, sys.stdout)
```

**Output:**

```
john
```

...because 'sam' is in triplicate whereas...

```
DuplicateGuideCheck(lst, sys.stdout, False)
```

...produces...

```
sam
john
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I got the answer and my code is working fine now.